# Up to date IndexedDB CRUD scenario for latest browsers?

Tags: indexeddb

As I understand it is IndexedDB is THE way to go for mostly cross browser solution to DB online.  Perhaps even using this polyfill for browsers such as FF.

I'm trying to find an extremely simple page that uses IndexedDB to initially populate a DB, read from it, and then update/insert records.

Everything I'm coming across seems to be outdated.

Eample: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/

This doesn't appear to work in my version of Chrome (21)

What are the latest and greatest samples on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB) contains up-to-date code. A problem is that Chrome 21 is not very up-to-date, it doesn't support `onupgradeneeded`. You can either do something like [this](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/07/using-indexeddb-api-today-the-indexeddb-polyfills/) to make it compatible with Chrome 21, or wait for Chrome 23 if you want to do things the most modern way (the latest developer builds seem to work well enough).

[Here is another recent tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/uidatabinding/) that works in Chrome 23, but won't in the current version.

Answer (score 0):

I try to demonstrate best usage for IndexdbDB through javascript wrapper http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/starting/setup.html  Try copy and paste the code snippet to dev console and try a bit. You get very good feel and confident on IndexedDB. it is very easy to understand how to use IndexedDB through the hand-on tutorials.